# cache query using entityframework-plus extension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I want to use [entityframework-plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-cache) extension to cache some of my queries,
but it does not have any option to select specific items and cache them, as I read its document, it caches all of the columns like this :

```
ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive).FromCache()
```

but I have something like this:

```
db.tbl_Brand_To_Product.Where(x => x.tbl_BrandID == id).Select(x => x.tbl_ProductID)
```

I want to select just **tbl_ProductID** IDs not **select ***

anybody works with this extension? is there any option to do this ? or even is there any other extension which can cache my query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the response of its developer:

[image: This is the response of its developer]

after some search, I found **HttpContext.Cache** method to cache my results.

Answer (score 0):

`FromCache()` method can only be used on `IQueryable<TEntity>` objects. As your `.Select(x => x.tbl_ProductID)` instruction returns an `IQueryable<int>` (or whatever type `tbl_ProductID` is) you won't be able to use the extension method.

You can download the whole source code from GitHub and see the class file CacheExtensions.cs